# Android achartengine legend not working on refresh

Tags: android, achartengine, legend

Developing an application for Android that uses achartengine. The problem that I'm having is whenever I refresh my pie chart with new data, the legend shows more values than it should.

Screen of initial load:

[image]

Screen after a refresh of data:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class DevicesOfflineActivity extends BaseActionBarActivity 
{
    private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { 0xFF008000, 0xFFB3B300, Color.RED };
    private static String[] NAME_LIST = new String[] { "Online", "Stale", "Offline" };

    private List<Integer> devicesOnline;

    private int online;
    private int stale;
    private int offline;

    private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("");
    private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    private GraphicalView mChartView;

    private void setGraph()
    {
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(30);
        mRenderer.setShowTickMarks(true);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 15 });
        mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);

        int[] vals = new int[] {online, stale, offline};

        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) 
        {
            mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + " " + vals[i], vals[i]);
            SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        }

        if (mChartView != null) 
        {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();` and `mSeries = new CategorySeries("");` to the beginning of `setGraph()` but my app crashes with those.

The closest solution I have is this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) 
    {
        if (mSeries.getItemCount() <= i) mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + " " + vals[i], vals[i]);
        else mSeries.set(i, NAME_LIST[i] + " " + vals[i], vals[i]);
        SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
        if (mRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount() <= i) mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        else mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(i, renderer);
    }
```

But my legend is gray after I refresh when I do that like so:

[image]

Also, `mRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount()` keeps increasing by 3 every refresh while `mSeries.getItemCount()` remains at 3. I can't find a way to replace the existing items in mRenderer.

Anyone familiar with achartengine that has a good solution?

Edit:

I think I have made some progress. I got the item counts to stay at 3, but now the legend is all red.

Code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) 
    {
        if (mSeries.getItemCount() <= i) mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + " " + vals[i], vals[i]);
        else mSeries.set(i, NAME_LIST[i] + " " + vals[i], vals[i]);
        SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
        if (mRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount() <= i) mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        else
        {
            mRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i));
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(i, renderer);
        }
    }
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
    mSeries.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) 
    {
        mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + " " + vals[i], vals[i]);
        SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
        if (mRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount() <= i) mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        else
        {
            mRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i));
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(i, renderer);
        }
    }
```